# play.libs.WS.WSRequestHolder.get() cuts off parts of request?

Tags: java, web-services, playframework, get, playframework-2.2

My program should call `https://somepath.com/terminallocation/?msisdn=number" , it appears however that everything after ? is cut off. I spend the last 3 hours on this and I have only limited amount of tries. It would be nice if anyone could help.

```
public static play.libs.F.Promise<Result> locationControllerGET(
        String number) {

    String feedUrl = "https://somepath.com/terminallocation/?msisdn="
            + number;
    Logger.debug(WS.url(feedUrl)
            .setAuth("user", "password", com.ning.http.client.Realm.AuthScheme.BASIC).getUrl().toString());

    final play.libs.F.Promise<Result> resultPromise = WS.url(feedUrl)
            .setAuth("48509237274", "Y7A7HNM3EFF3LF", com.ning.http.client.Realm.AuthScheme.BASIC).get()
            .map(new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
                        return ok("");                  
            });
    return resultPromise;
}
```

Console output from logger:

```
[debug] application - https://somepath.com/terminallocation/?msisdn=number
```

I also checked with `Logger.debug.debuf(deedUrl)` and it was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section after the `?` is considered a "query parameter" and needs to be specified separately as part of the `WSRequestHolder`'s Builder pattern. So, using the `setQueryParameter(String name, String value)` method from the [`WS.WSRequestHolder` API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/libs/WS.WSRequestHolder.html#setQueryParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/libs/WS.WSRequestHolder.html#setQueryParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String feedUrl = "https://somepath.com/terminallocation/";

final play.libs.F.Promise<Result> resultPromise = WS.url(feedUrl)
        .setQueryParameter("msisdn", number)
        .setAuth("48509237274", "Y7A7HNM3EFF3LF", com.ning.http.client.Realm.AuthScheme.BASIC).get()
        .map(new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
                    return ok("");                  
});
```